# Vagrant error, not receiving version information from VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant error, not receiving version information from VirtualBox

```
C:\Users\Kate\PhpstormProjects\codes>vagrant up
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/config.rb:83:in `block in missing_interpolation_argument_handler': missing interpolation argument :vboxmanage in "Vagrant detected that VirtualBox appears installed on your system,\nbut calls to detect the version are returning empty. This is often\nindicative of installation issues with VirtualBox. Please verify\nthat VirtualBox is properly installed. As a final verification,\nplease run the following command manually and verify a version is\noutputted:\n\n%{vboxmanage} --version" ({:_key=>:virtualbox_version_empty, :_namespace=>"vagrant.errors"} given) (I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I hate to ask it...Virtualbox is actually installed?

Comment: yes, it is installed

Comment: @СайковаЕкатерина was your issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open your "Task Manager" and kill all Virtualbox instances and then try again "vagrant up" and after it successfully started "vagrant ssh". It should work again.

Sometimes if you update Windows you have to uninstall and install Virtualbox again and restart your computer for it to work.

Comment: I reinstalled Virtualbox 3 times, and tried the latest and previous versions,  vagrant provides all the same mistake

Comment: Was the VM working with Vagrant before? Can you start the VM with the Virtualbox GUI ?

Comment: If you haven't done this, try it:
download and install Git for Windows: http://git-scm.com/download/win
in your PhpStorm go to:
File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal
change the shell path from:
cmd.exe
to: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i
With this you'll have a linux like command line in PhpStorm. 
Kill all instances of Virtualbox if any is running, then try to start your VM with "vagrant up" from the PhpStorm terminal. Sometimes vagrant isn't working for me in the windows console and this solution just works for me.

Comment: Check the state of the VM's with vagrant global-status. Try to make a new VM with vagrant and a new Vagrantfile. If this doesn't work, uninstall Virtualbox and vagrant and install them as described on the vagrant website.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5309).

Replace "0.1" in \lib\vagrant\util\io.rb with "1.0" line 28